# How do i code a master page and link it to my css style sheet and other web pages?

Tags: html, master-pages, stylesheet, notepad

I am currently trying to create a website from scratch using HTML, CSS and Javascript code, which i am teaching myself. I have created a webpage and a css that link fine, however i want to have multiple pages on my website so i need a master page so that my theme layout is the same throughout.

I am using notepad (very basic i know) i using windows 7. How do i code my master page so that it links to my other pages (yet to create) and also links in my css file? I have saved a file in notepad along with my first page and style sheet called master.master ,however i'm not sure it is picking up all of the content correctly.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you are doing is trying create a website with a theme running throughout each page.

This is what external style sheets are for.

Basically by including this style sheet in each html page, you are giving youself the ability to style each page using the same theme.

Comment: So when you say this do you mean i can basically use my css style sheet as the master page - including the layout i want to run on all webpages and then link the stylesheet to each and every page? Thanks. e.g i don't an external master page?